# Python Syntax Error(invaild syntax)

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

I'm new in python and I have problem with 'Syntax Error:invaild syntax' when i want compile my code in a module.
after I compile the code i see this :

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKYdD.png)

Comment: You forgot the comma in your set literal.

Comment: Why are you using curly braces? (`{}`) This is not Pythonic...

Comment: @Joel thanks! it worked :)

Comment: Your usage of `print` seems to indicate, that you run your code with Python 3.x. How do you think `type(user)` could be something different than `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use curly braces . Python uses curly braces for dictionaries .